# mysql replication delay very serious

Tags: mysql, replication

We use a ssd disk for master database and SATA disk for slave.

On high write load (300 writes/s), slave delay is very serious. I have set:

- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0`
- increased `innodb_log_file_size`

on the slave, but the delay continues.

the slave is for backup only, no read or write request.

Seconds_Behind_Master: 92265, continue increasing.

some conf:

innodb_buffer_pool_size=15G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M

```
du -hs mysql
338G    mysql

iostat
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sde               0.00    73.00   34.50  185.00   552.00  7086.00    69.59     5.63   25.63   19.19   26.83   3.65  80.20
```

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to the site. Can you give us some more information on your setup? Does your application use this slave for read queries? How is the load on the slave, cpu-wise? Is your sata disk saturated? Some stats would be good.

Comment: Questions : Is the Slave read-only? Are any writes coming to the Slave besides the SQL thread? How high is Seconds_Behind_Master ? Is the Slave read-heavy ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about something similar on [MySQL replication: most important config parameters for performance on slave server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41085/mysql-replication-most-important-config-parameters-for-performance-on-slave-ser/41210#41210)

Basically you should focus on the follow variables on slave (see the other post for more information):

- `innodb_buffer_pool_size`
- `innodb_log_file_size`
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`
- `innodb_doublewrite`
- `innodb_flush_method`
- `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct`
- `sync_binlog`
- `sync_master_info`
- `sync_relay_log`
- `sync_relay_log_info`

One thing to have in mind is that the slave have just a single thread to process all writes from master, let's say you master are able to handle 300 connections simultaneously, it's 300 threads writing at the same time (respecting locking issues, disk, ...)  but on the slave you have just a single one to deal with all this transactions.

## Suggestion:

If you use MySQL 5.6 and have your data partitioned per database, you can take advantage of [slave-parallel-workers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_slave-parallel-workers)

Answer (score 0):

If the slave is for backup and read-only, you can remove unnecessary index such as full-text and non-unique index in the slave. It will reduce the chance of indexing and read-write I/O.